# Android nested layout with layout_weight

Tags: android-layout

I would like to create left and right reserved spaces (LinearLayout) on screen which give me felexiblitiy to ensure my UI is working in different size of screen as I want, 
and in middle create a TableLayout to apply views and contorls, everything good great 
except TableRow - android:layout_width is became zero, TableLayout width is not really zero however I had to put android:layout_width="0dp" for TableLayout to force android:layout_weight="4" working

how can I tell TableRow to take actual parnt(TableLayout) width

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget32"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget33"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget34"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="4">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/widget64"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/widget72"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="I m here" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget35"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>
```